# How to stream output of Process as it happens?

Tags: c#, .net

I got this code from microsoft support site 
and it allows you to run a external process from your application
it give output after the execution of program but i would like to stream output as it happens on screen
how do i do it?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Way_Back_Downloader
{

internal class RunWget
{
    internal static string Run(string exeName, string argsLine, int timeoutSeconds)
    {
        StreamReader outputStream = StreamReader.Null;
        string output = "";
        bool success = false;

        try
        {
            Process newProcess = new Process();
            newProcess.StartInfo.FileName = exeName;
            newProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = argsLine;
            newProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            newProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            newProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            newProcess.Start();



            if (0 == timeoutSeconds)
            {
                outputStream = newProcess.StandardOutput;
                output = outputStream.ReadToEnd();

                newProcess.WaitForExit();
            }
            else
            {
                success = newProcess.WaitForExit(timeoutSeconds * 1000);

                if (success)
                {
                    outputStream = newProcess.StandardOutput;
                    output = outputStream.ReadToEnd();
                }

                else
                {
                    output = "Timed out at " + timeoutSeconds + " seconds waiting for " + exeName + " to exit.";
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw (new Exception("An error occurred running " + exeName + ".", exception));
        }
        finally
        {
            outputStream.Close();
        }
        return "\t" + output;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What you want to achieve ? This is not a way to ask question.

Comment: stream output as it happens rather than wait for it to finish and show output @KaushikKishore

Answer (score 1):

`ReadToEnd` obviously won't work - it *can't* return before the stream is closed (or it wouldn't have read to the end). Instead, write a loop using [`ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
string line;
while ((line = outputStream.ReadLine()) != null) {
   Console.WriteLine("Have line: " + line);
}
```

Also, keeping [RedirectStandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx) as `false` (the default) won't allow the output to be captured but it *will* display the output immediately on the screen in this context.